# google API calendar watch doesn't work but channel is created

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I try to listen on my calendar change  events ([google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch)).

I did everything from Google console side, domains - OK, everything is verified and I succeeded to create channel. Also i succeeded to get `sync` message with right headers (see below). From docs:

> Sync message
>
> After creating a new notification channel to watch a resource, the
>   Google Calendar API sends a sync message to indicate that
>   notifications are starting. The X-Goog-Resource-State HTTP header
>   value for these messages is sync. Because of network timing issues, it
>   is possible to receive the sync message even before you receive the
>   watch method response.

That mean that `notifications are starting`

However when I change something in `snaggs@comp.com` account -
**nothing happens, no request sends to callback** : `'https://dev-api.mycompany/google-watch/'`

This is my working code:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
var _ = require('underscore-node');


var uuid = require('node-uuid');

  // ......

                     var channel_id = uuid.v1();


                        _auth.credentials = {
                            access_token: _token.access_token,
                            token_type: _token.token_type,
                            refresh_token: _token.refresh_token,
                            expiry_date: _token.expiry_date
                        };

                        var data = {
                            auth: _auth,
                            calendarId: _token.provider_email, 
                            singleEvents: true,
                            orderBy: 'startTime',
                            resource: {
                                id: channel_id,
                                token: 'email='+_token.provider_email,
                                address: 'https://dev-api.mycompany/google-watch/',
                                type: 'web_hook',
                                params: {
                                    ttl: '36000'
                                }
                            }

                        };

                        calendar.events.watch(data, function (err, response) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                                 return;
                            }
                        });
```

When I start above mentioned snippets of code i get response:

```
{
  "kind": "api#channel",
  "id": "277fa000-d4b6-12e5-ab58-e7afaf85ea65",
  "resourceId": "C7vFL07CYfqaHy3vDss4qugWDfk",
  "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/snaggs@comp.com/events?orderBy=START_TIME&singleEvents=true&alt=json",
  "token": "email=snaggs@comp.com",
  "expiration": "1455667451000"
}
```

And in `'https://dev-api.mycompany/google-watch/'`  URL I get `sync` message regards to documents, like (See [google-apps/calendar/v3/push](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push)):

```
{
  "host": "dev-api.mycompany",
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate",
  "user-agent": "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)",
  "x-goog-channel-expiration": "Tue, 16 Feb 2016 22:44:51 GMT",
  "x-goog-channel-id": "277fa000-d4b6-12e5-ab58-e7afaf85ea65",
  "x-goog-channel-token": "email=snaggs@comp.com",
  "x-goog-message-number": "1",
  "x-goog-resource-id": "C7vFL07CYfqaHy3vDss4qugWDfk",
  "x-goog-resource-state": "sync",
  "x-goog-resource-uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/snaggs@comp.com/events?orderBy=START_TIME&singleEvents=true&alt=json",
  "x-forwarded-for": "56.102.7.132",
  "x-forwarded-port": "443",
  "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
  "content-length": "0",
  "connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

**but not `exists` message**

Do I miss something?

please help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have been using Push Notifications for a few years and noticed that for the last 24 hours we did not receive any notifications across several thousand calendars.

Like you we can create/stop a channel but no notifications are received for changes as normal.

As of about an hour ago we are receiving them again.  Please try your channel again as it may be a glitch on the Google Push side of things that has been resolved.

Comment: was an Outage @ Google.  It is normally very reliable.  You need to build some polling for changes in your application to cater for the scenario where PUSH fails.